# Multiple radio buttons and two separate "Submit" buttons where the logic would flow depending on the options chosen

Tags: php, forms, radio-button, submit, submit-button

I'm trying to create a "Thank you" page where a user lands after he/she has opted into one of our forms. On that page there will be an option for the user to choose a free CD as a gift and will only have to pay for shipping. I would like to give the user an option to either choose a physical CD or a digital MP3. The logic here is that first I provide a user with selection of 4 CDs that I connect to each radio button. Then below that there will be the first *Submit* button that will say something like "Yes, please mail be a CD." Below the first button there will be a second *Submit* button that will say something like "Send me the download link instead". Thus if the user clicks on any of the radio buttons and then clicks on the first *Submit* button, they will be taken to the shopping cart for that CD where they will be prompted to pay the shipping charges for the CD. If the user click on that same radio button, but then clicks on the second *Submit* button, they will be taken to link to download it. The third link below would just take the user past the page if he chooses to opt out of this offer.

I can't get the script to work correctly for me. Here is what I have so far:

```
<?PHP

$option1 = 'unchecked';
$option2 = 'unchecked';
$option3 = 'unchecked';
$option4 = 'unchecked';


if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) 

        {

    $selected_radio = $_POST['cd_choice'];

        if ($selected_radio == 'option1') 
        {
            $option1 = 'checked';
                     ?>
                      <a href="#">Purchase link 1</a>
                     <?php

        }
        else if ($selected_radio == 'option2') 
        {
        $option2 = 'checked';
                     ?>
                      <a href="#">Purchase link 2</a>
                     <?php          
        }
        else if ($selected_radio == 'option3') 
        {
        $option3 = 'checked';
                     ?>
                      <a href="#">Purchase link 3</a>
                     <?php          
        }
        else if ($selected_radio == 'option4') 
        {
        $option4 = 'checked';
                     ?>
                      <a href="#">Purchase link 4</a>
                     <?php          
        }
    }
else
    {
    $selected_radio = $_POST['cd_choice'];

        if ($selected_radio == 'option1') 
        {
         $option1 = 'checked';
                     ?>
                      <a href="#">Download link 1</a>
                     <?php          
        }
        else if ($selected_radio == 'option2') 
        {
         $option2 = 'checked';
                     ?>
                      <a href="#">Download link 2</a>
                     <?php          
        }
        else if ($selected_radio == 'option3') 
        {
         $option3 = 'checked';
                     ?>
                      <a href="#">Download link 3</a>
                     <?php          
        }
        else if ($selected_radio == 'option4') 
        {
         $option4 = 'checked';
                     ?>
                      <a href="#">Download link 4</a>
                     <?php          
        }
    } 
?>
```

Here's what I have for the HTML portion of it:

```
<body>

<FORM NAME ="form1" METHOD ="POST" ACTION ="radioButton_test.php">

  <INPUT TYPE = 'Radio' Name ='cd_choice'  value= 'option1' <?PHP print $option1; ?>>
  This is the first CD
  <INPUT TYPE = 'Radio' Name ='cd_choice'  value= 'option2' <?PHP print $option2; ?>>
  This is the second CD
  <INPUT TYPE = 'Radio' Name ='cd_choice'  value= 'option3' <?PHP print $option3; ?>>
  This is the third CD
  <INPUT TYPE = 'Radio' Name ='cd_choice'  value= 'option4' <?PHP print $option4; ?>>
  This is the fourth CD
<P>
<center><INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name = "Submit1"  VALUE = "Yes, please mail me a CD"></center>
<p><center><INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name = "Submit2"  VALUE = "Send me download link instead"></center></p>
<div align="center"><a href="#">No thanks. </a></div>
</FORM>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've taken the liberty of cleaning up your HTML a little - generally HTML is lowercase these days - but essentially you can change the action of your form depending on which button is clicked very easily with JavaScript:

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="POST" action="radioButton_test.php">
   <center><input type="Submit" name="Submit1" value="Yes, please mail me a CD" onclick="this.form.action='test1.php';alert(this.form.action);"></center>
   <p><center><input type="Submit" name="Submit2" value="Send me download link instead" onclick="this.form.action='test2.php';alert(this.form.action);"></center></p>
</form>
```

You will want to change the form names "test1.php" and "test2.php" to your actual php script names and remove the `alert(this.form.action);` code, but this should do what you want.

Alternately, if you want to post back to your same script, you can just check for the value of the submit button. The submit button you click will be passed in the post, while the other one won't.

```
if ( !empty($_POST['Submit1']) )
```

Or

```
if ( isset($_POST['Submit1']) )
```

Or

```
if ( isset($_POST['Submit1']) && $_POST['Submit1'] == 'Yes, please mail me a CD' )
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, Revent! When I placed your code for the submit buttons, it basically takes me to the same link regardless of what option I chose with the radio button. It looks like that's because 'onclick="this.form.action='test1.php'' is embedded into the Submit button and will always take me to whatever page I specify for that action. Or am I doing something wrong? What I actually need is for the user to be taken to whatever selection was picked with the radio button and then the submit button will navigate the user to either the shopping cart [hard copy] disk purchase or MP3 link

Comment: Ya, I didn't put the rest of the form elements into the form for my example, so you will have to put them back in. Since the onclick on the buttons is just changing the form action, whatever inputs you have in the form should still work when you submit it. Obviously you would change "test1.php" to your actual script name. Please accept my answer if it was helpful to you. Thanks!